# fetching data in React useEffect() after adding item to database using graphql and axios crashes the app

Tags: reactjs, graphql

> Initially the **initialFetch** is true, so whenever the component renders graphql and axios fetch data from db. Then **initialFetch** is set to false.

> Once an event is added to db via graphql and axios there **added** state variable is set to true. Since useEffect depends on **added** it should re-render the component and should fetch the data from db. But for some reason it fails as I mentioned below axios fails at communicating with the server.

> ***Note! I Used GraphQL for fetching data from MongoDB***

```
const [added, setAdded] = useState(false)
const [initialFetch, setInitialFetch] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEvents = () => {   
    
        console.log('inside fetchEvents()')
        const headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        
        const requestBody = {
            query: `
                query {
                    events {
                        _id
                        title
                        description
                        price
                    }
                }
            `
        }
        
        const body = JSON.stringify(requestBody)
        
        console.log('awaiting for events from db')
        
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/graphql', body, {headers}).then((res) => {
            console.log('events fetched from db')
            setEvents(res.data.data.events)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    
    if (initialFetch) {
        setInitialFetch(false)
        console.log('initial fetch')
        fetchEvents()
    }
    
    if (added) {
        setAdded(false)
        console.log('added, fetching again')
        fetchEvents()
    }
    
}, [added, initialFetch])
```

> Here axios fails to add data to db and **catch(err)** block is executed after waiting over 2 minutes and the app crashes. The below code where axios posts data continuously keeps failing every time I try.

```
const handleConfirm = () => {
    
    // request to backend
    const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${authContext.token}`
        }
    
    const requestBody = {
        query: `
            mutation {
                createEvent(title: "${title}", description: "${desc}", price: ${price}, date: "${date}") {
                    _id
                    title
                    description
                    price
                }
            }
        `
    }
    
    const body = JSON.stringify(requestBody)

    console.log('adding to db')
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/graphql', body, {headers}).then((res) => {
        setAdded(true)
        console.log('added item to db')
        console.log(res.data)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

the initial fetch happens and I add data to db. After adding to db I should be re-fetched the events from db, instead that re-render fails and the app crashes.

Comment: ` if (added) {
        fetchEvents()
        setAdded(false)
    }
    
    fetchEvents()` - `fetchEvents` is fired with and without condition ... `        setAdded(false)` changes `added` (no matter what value) and reruns effect by dependency on `added`

Comment: check/show raw network mutation request ... variables should be passed by 'variables' object, not by string manipulations

Answer (score 0):

That error is a classic sign that you have an infinite loop in your code. It is particularly common when that infinite loop is due to infinite recursion. Each time you call a function, JS has to allocate some stack space for the stackframe. If that function always calls itself, then it will keep trying to allocate more and more space until eventually, it crashes due to having no more memory available to allocate from.

Try removing the unguarded call to `fetchEvents()` in your `useEffect()` code block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the app will definitely crash as it is updating the state recursively and indefinitely.

as every time the value of `added` is updated the `useEffect` is fired and as the `useEffect` fires it triggers axios.post which inturn again updates the state `added`